# Parameters in Django Page Redirection

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, redirect

I have the following code in views:

```
def submit_affective(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    choice=request.POST['aff_choices']
    urlid=request.POST['url_list']
    url = Url.objects.get(id=urlid)
    aff_result=Affective.objects.create(
        affective=choice, url=url
        )
    return redirect('detail_affective',id=url.id)

def detail_affective(request,id):
boring_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Boring',url.id=id).count()
confusing_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Confusing',url.id=id).count()
engaging_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Engaging',url.id=id).count()
context = {
    'boring_count':boring_count,
    'confusing_count':confusing_count,
    'engaging_count':engaging_count,
}
return render(request,'feedback/detail_affective.html',context)
```

I want to show the number of "boring","confusing","engaging" in `detail_affective` only for that URL for which choice has been submitted in `submit_affective`. Please tell me the problem in my code. Am I passing the url id to detail_affective correctly? And is my way of filtering correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `url.id` expression as filter argument, just use `url_id` instead:

```
boring_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Boring',url_id=id).count()
confusing_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Confusing',url_id=id).count()
engaging_count=Affective.objects.filter(affective='Engaging',url_id=id).count()
```

Also you need to add `id` as url agrument argument to the urlpattern:

```
path('detail_affective/<int:id>',views.detail_affective,name='detail_affective')
```

Comment: It's not working. I think there is some problem is passing of url id from submit to detail. If I remove the id from parameter, it works.

Comment: @PrabhjeetSingh can you show your urls? You need to add `id` as url argument.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
 path('create_url/',views.create_url,name='create_url'),
 path('submit_affective/',views.submit_affective,name='submit_affective'),
 path('submit_cognitive/',views.submit_cognitive,name='submit_cognitive'),
 path('thanks/',views.thanks,name='thanks'),
 path('detail_affective/',views.detail_affective,name='detail_affective'),
 path('detail_cognitive/',views.detail_cognitive,name='detail_cognitive'), 
 path('',views.index,name='index'),
]

Comment: @PrabhjeetSingh check updated answer. You need to add `id` to the urlpattern.